# smarty - How to separate values with comma

Tags: smarty

```
{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|nl2br nofilter}
```

it putout the each value in a new line

I want to separate values by comma, nl2br  should be replaced with?

Answer (score 0):

This should works:
`{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall'|replace:"\r\n":',' nofilter}`